# BigQuery + GDPR: How to remove PII data from BigQuery snapshots?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In our RTBF (request to be forgotten) workflow, we have multiple methods of removing PII from various BigQuery tables. This includes removing a row completely, masking personally identifiable information, or deleting the values of certain cells in tables.

We're also building out our backup strategies and it is my understanding that snapshots will retain the PII that we're "forgetting". So, in the event we need to restore from backup, PII that would have been "forgotten" from our source tables will be "remembered" and show up again.

**Is it feasible to remove PII from snapshots?** Would it require dropping the whole snapshot altogether?

The following query:

```sql
update `project.dataset.table-2023-03-28T14_10_10`
set email = '<MASKED>'
where id = '<id>'
```

results in the following error:

```
Table project.dataset.table-2023-03-28T14_10_10 is a snapshot, and snapshots are immutable.
```

Comment: No more than that: `snapshots are immutable`

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I think you're right which is frustrating as it's the easiest backup strategy to implement for our instance. I've noticed that table clones are an alternative that are editable but a little more finicky to setup (no expirations). Will continue research to identify best backup strategy that also addresses GDPR concerns

Comment: It's not a problem for GDPR. You simply have to mention in your GDPR registry that you keep technical backups for X days and then the data are deleted. And it's possible that "forgotten" data are still in the backup until deletion (and add that in the legal part also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Data Masking` is not compatible with snapshots, and as mentioned, snaphots are immutable. Luckily, if your table snapshots with PII have come to their expiration dates, **BigQuery will delete those table snapshots**. The idea of [Table Cloning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-snapshots-restore#restore_a_table_snapshot) is also great since you can create a new table out of it with the particular data included in your snapshot. You can try to restore from your table snapshots and modify it to manage your PII in your newly created standard table. Making it via console or using this syntax are two of the few options:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_PROJECT_ID.TABLE_DATASET_NAME.NEW_TABLE_NAME
CLONE SNAPSHOT_PROJECT_ID.SNAPSHOT_DATASET_NAME.SNAPSHOT_NAME;
```

Comment: Accepting this answer as it confirmed my initial thoughts. We're progressing with snapshots for now but debating using clones if the need arises